# If Changes in connection string is sufficient to access sql server 2012 instead of sql 2000 in production application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working in a task in which my dot application have to access sql server 2012 instead of sql server 2000. Currently I don't have source code for the same and want to change it directly in connection string of web.config file.

I want to know that only changing connection string in deployed application is sufficient to access sql server 2012 database if its previous database was in sql server 2000.

Answer (score 2):

In theory yes. Assuming that you get your security settings correct (in the updated connection string), the app *should* connect to the new DB. However... if the app used any features in SQL 2000 that are no longer available or compatible in SQL 2012, or used a weird DB driver, then you'll run into problems. It will probably be very apparent once you run your app.

Probably best if you can isolate the system (app + db server), placing into a VM environment. Then change the connection string and TEST TEST TEST.